# Transformar caracteres maiúsculos de uma entrada em caracteres minúsculos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho esse simples formulário e um código jquery que preenche automaticamente o campo 'email' com o primeiro nome do campo 'nome' e acrescenta '@dominio.com.br' para formar um endereço de e-mail. Como faço para que, além disso, ele transforme os caracteres maiúsculos do campo 'nome' em minúsculos mas somente no campo 'email'?

jquery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("input[name=nome]").change(function () {
      var nome = $(this).val();
      var pEspaco = nome.indexOf(' ');
      var nomeFinal = nome;
      if (pEspaco != -1) {
          nomeFinal = nome.substr(0, pEspaco);
      }
      $("input[name=email]").val(nomeFinal + "@dominio.com.br");
  });
});
```

html:

```
        <form name="campos" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>"> 
            <label>
                <span>Nome:</span>
                <input type="text" name="nome"  placeholder="" /><br>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Cargo:</span>
                <input type="text" name="cargo" placeholder="" /><br>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Celular:</span>
                <input type="text" name="celular" placeholder="Exemplo: 44 9876 9876" /><br>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>e-mail:</span>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="" /><br>
            </label>
            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviar" />
            <button type="submit" class="envio" title="Enviar mensagem"></button> 
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o método [.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) que é nativo em JavaScript.

Assim ficaria por exemplo:

```
$("input[name=email]").val(nomeFinal.toLowerCase() + "@dominio.com.br");
```

Pode simplificar um pouco e usar assim:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("input[name=nome]").change(function () {
        var partes = this.value.split(' ');
        var email = partes[0];
        $("input[name=email]").val(email.toLowerCase() + "@dominio.com.br");
    });
});
```

Se quiser o ultimo nome, pode usar `var email = partes[partes.length - 1];`

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Stf6J/1